# PHP accessing function variables in HTML

Tags: php, html, function, pdo, echo

First, sorry for the poorly phrased title question. I am writing a small program where the login() function, when called, gets the 'user name' and 'user level' from a database. If the entry is valid, the user is brought to the logout page. All it does is welcome the user and prompt them to log out. However, it is not displaying the user information when I use the following code:

logoutForm.inc.html...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Farm-Fresh_key.png">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id = "wrapper">
        <div id="masthead">
        <h2>Welcome, <?php echo $userName; ?>!</h2>
            <h3>Your current user level is <?php echo $userLevel; ?></h3>
              <form action method="post" name="logoutForm">
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Log Out" />
                </p>
             </form>
         </div> 
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

functions.php...

```
<?php
function login($userName) 
{
if (empty($userName)){
    echo '<h2>You forgot to enter something</h2>
          <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=login.php" />';
}
else
    {

      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:3307;dbname=users", "root", "");
      $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE email = :username");
      $result->bindParam(':username', $userName);
      $result->execute();
      $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      if($row > 0) {
        if ($row['userLevel'] == 'A')
        {
            $userLevel = 'Admin';
        }
        elseif ($row['userLevel'] == 'M')
        {
            $userLevel = 'Member';
        }

        header("Location: includes/logoutForm.inc.html");
      }
      else
      {
          echo '<h2>That entry is INVALID</h2>
                <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=login.php" />';
      }
    }
}


function logout($userName)
    {
        session_start();

        echo '<title>Logout</title>
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Farm-Fresh_key.png">
            <meta charset="utf-8">';
        $_SESSION['username'] = array();
        session_destroy();
        $name = session_name(); $expire = strtotime('-1 year'); $params = session_get_cookie_params(); $path = $params['path']; $domain = $params['domain']; $secure = $params['secure']; $httponly = $params['httponly'];
        setcookie($name, '', $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);

        die('<h3>You have successfully logged out</h3>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=login.php" />');
    }
```

Not to mention that the logout() function is completely screwed up. Taking this one problem at a time. Thanks for looking, please help if you can.

Comment: well unless you have altered your server settings, html files are not usually processed as php. Also, the fact it is named logoutForm. **inc** .html suggests it is intended to be included in a php file, not accessed directly

Comment: You need to pass the variables the `header` if you are going to redirect otherwise they can't see your `$userLevel` and `$userName`. You would have to use a `$_GET` or include the file instead of handing it off.

Comment: I agree with Steve, and would also like to point out - your login/logout functions are exactly that - functions.  You should be calling the function to determine if the user is valid, and based on the function response give output to the user.

Comment: @JamesShaver Thanks. I'm trying to use a php script as a controller. Even if I use a switch inside that script that calls the login/logout function, and displays a logout/login html page based on result, how to pass the data retrieved from pdo _into_ the html?

Comment: @Rasclatt That sounds like a cool way to do it! How to go about passing variables with the header?

Comment: But you're not using the functions as anything but a way to echo results.

Comment: @James Shaver True...so long as you strip it out, it's not that big of a deal to forward...but I don't think it's a great idea anyway.

Comment: `"how to pass the data retrieved from pdo into the html"` If you include the html file(s), rather than redirect to them, then the variables from the parent file are in scope for the included file. I think you are quite lost, and should probably look for a comprehensive tutorial, or better yet pick a nice microframework with good documentation  and go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the login to persist, you need to store the information in a session (the session could be stored in a database if you need it to persist for longer periods than browsing sessions):

```
  if($row > 0) {

    // start the session, you might want to do that at the top of your script
    session_start();

    if ($row['userLevel'] == 'A')
    {
        $_SESSION['userLevel'] = 'Admin';
    }
    elseif ($row['userLevel'] == 'M')
    {
        $_SESSION['userLevel'] = 'Member';
    }
```

Now you can start a session in your logged-in pages and check if the variable is set and what the exact user permissions are.

**Note:** Do not use a query string to pass these variables around as mentioned in the comments. That will allow anybody to pretend to be logged-in with the permissions they want just by altering the query string. A session is stored server-side and can therefore not be manipulated by the visitor.

Comment: Yeah sorry I read that wrong, I thought he was trying to pass variables after logging out, not in...because yes that is a bad idea!

Comment: @Rasclatt I can imagine, I was confused by the name of where the visitor is redirected as well. Thought I'd mention it to be safe and to avoid further confusion.